# WiFi has no internet access, but it does

Tags: internet

I'm on Android 6.0.1. I'm writing this question while connected to a friend's WiFi, with mobile data turned off. But my phone says "connected, no internet access", and there's a ! by the WiFi indicator on the bar along the top of the screen.

I think Android thinking there's no internet is stopping certain apps from working, whereas others don't seem to care (and work).

Why is Android thinking there's no internet when there is? Can I assure it that there is internet?

Answer (score 2):

"Connected, no internet access" means that the test that Android uses to check if there is Internet access is failing. The url or method used to test if Internet is working varies by Android version and on 6.0 it uses `connectivitycheck.gstatic.com/generate_204` as the test. - [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493517/detect-if-android-device-has-internet-connection/25816086#25816086)

"Internet" is just a network, if the routing, access, DNS resolution, etc. pieces are all there, the "Internet" is going to work... regardless if the test Android does to see if it is working fails or not, although you may have to specifically tell your device (via a pop-up toast prompt or setting in WiFi - Advanced) to stay connected to that WiFi network.

Why the test fails? Hard to say, but something in your friends network or their ISP is blocking the check your device makes to test if the Internet is working.

Comment: Thanks, I'm on android 6.0.1 (as in question) and a Nexus 5. Wondering if there was a way to get it to try its test again or something. Some apps don't seem to try accessing the 'net if android thinks it's not working.

Comment: @artfulrobot Actually, that is easy... Just forget the network and reconnect to it. I have this issue at a hotel I frequent quite often, works every time.

Answer (score 0):

Does the friend's Wi-Fi have internet connection? It's possible that you may be connected to your friend's router, but there's no internet connection. You may need to have the router restarted.

It's also possible that some other device connected to the router is hogging all the bandwidth, leaving nothing for your device.

Comment: Nope, that's the thing, i can browse the web and fetch emails no problem!

Comment: @artfulrobot Have you tried restarting your phone? Might just be stale data / information.